# build failed after nuxt update with npm

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

nuxt build failed after run npm update with this log

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
ReferenceError: [BABEL] /home/mahdi/apps/*******/.nuxt/client.js: Unknown option: base.configFile. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```

Comment: You didn't changed any code there? Can you share some of your relevant configuration?

Comment: no i did't change any thing just update dependencies with `npm update` yes i can share what do you want to see ?

Comment: Some relevant files looking at the error: nuxt config, babel config and having a diff between your `package.json` would be a good start (what were the old versions and which ones are erroring). That way, we could look for breaking changes in the changelogs.

Comment: i tried too many ways finally its fixed by install `babel-core` and `babel-loader` idk why but its works for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried too many ways finally its fixed by install babel-core and babel-loader idk why but its works for me

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: If you want the answer, it's in the config files. Or you can also YOLO it like you did.